# Move(style) marker using attribute on referencing element

Tags: css, svg, line

Let say I have a following marker (I want to have only one marker element in dom):

```
<marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="22.5" refY="0" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" fill="#000000"></path></marker>
```

And I'm using it with line to draw arrow on it:

```
<line stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" x1="1190.5337908659556" y1="814.1321248143822" x2="1183.09985813189" y2="-58.79906521075237" marker-end="url(#arrow)" display="inline"></line>
<line stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" x1="797.4477436706952" y1="325.5996932062993" x2="877.7838866381225" y2="631.7793113188723" marker-end="url(#arrow)" display="inline"></line>
```

Is there a way to move arrow along the line by using some attribute on line element referencing the marker?

Comment: Are your lines always straight?

Comment: Yes they are always straight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to animate the end point of the line that the marker is applied to.

In the example below, I have added a second line. Then we animate the `x2` and `y2` attributes from the start of that line to the end.  So it starts with zero length and end up the same as the original line.

```html
<svg viewBox="600 300 600 400">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="10" refY="0" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" fill="#000000"></path></marker>
  </defs>

  <!-- original path -->
  <line stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" x1="797.4477436706952" y1="325.5996932062993" x2="877.7838866381225" y2="631.7793113188723"/>

  <!-- original path -->
  <line stroke="none" stroke-width="0.5" x1="797.44" y1="325.59" x2="797.44" y2="325.59" marker-end="url(#arrow)">

     <animate attributeName="x2" from="797.44" to="877.78" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
     <animate attributeName="y2" from="325.59" to="631.77" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  </line>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's a really nice solution - the extra line as the marker path is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be possible with CSS. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute):

> The `‘display’` property does not apply to the `‘marker’` element

Markers are not directly rendered, so none of the usual methods for moving an element with CSS (transform/translate, positioning, margins, etc) are applicable to them.

To animate a marker, I think you'll need to use JS to animate the refX and refY values on it directly. Something like [Anime](http://animejs.com/) can help with that.